# JavaFX 8 TreeView : vertical scrollbar ignores horizontal scrollbar width

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, javafx-8

Because images are better than words, please find my problem below :

[image: No Horizontal Scrollbar as expected]

^ This is the right side of my TreeView, no scrollbar at bottom. It's expected because the content is not big enough.

[image: No Horizontal Scrollbar, but it should have]

^ **Here, you can see that the content is going under the vertical scrollbar. But the horizontal scrollbar does not show up as expected.**

[image: Horizontal Scrollbar]

^ Finally, the horizontal scrollbar shows up when the content touch the right side of the TreeView (and not the horizontal scroll bar).

I don't know if this behavior is expected, if it's a JavaFX bug or a bug in my application. Any help is welcome, thanks !

Comment: Pictures may be better than words, but the code reveals all.  :) Can you post your code that demonstrates the issue in an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/)?